# Cascading Multiple Qt Style Sheets in one application

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

Qt (and therefore PyQt) allows you to add a QSS (Qt Style Sheet) file to a QApplication, and one to each individual widget you create. You can set your application's style sheet with the following Python/PyQt code:

```
# app is a QApplication and styleSheet is a str.
app.setStyleSheet(styleSheet)
```

However, the `setStyleSheet()` function only allows you to specify one QSS file for the QApplication. This is unlike CSS, which allows any number of style sheets to be applied to a single webpage.

I'm writing a program in PyQt which will allow user-customizable themes. The program has a main QSS file, and themes should be able to contain additional QSS which would be cascaded on top of it. However, due to this apparent Qt limitation, this doesn't seem possible.

One idea I've thought of is that I could assign the program's default style sheet to the QApplication, and the current theme's style sheet to the QMainWindow. This seems like a workaround rather than a good idea, though.

Is there a good way to add two Qt Style Sheets like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
app.setStyleSheet(stylesheet1 + stylesheet2)
```

This will work the same as normal HTML, where the stylesheets are simply concatenated together in the order in which they appear in the document. After that, the standard rules of CSS specificity apply.